# Scroll to top after refreshing UITableView crashes after third cell (uncaught exception)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my refresh method I'm using the following code to scroll to top which is working fine, but when I scroll down after the third cell and hit refresh again it crashes the app with error terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NewsTbView.delegate = self;
    NewsTbView.dataSource = self;

    [self refresh]; 
}

-(void)refresh
{
    catName = @"All";
    self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.descArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.linkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.categoryNewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.imageCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.titleCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.descCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dateCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.linkCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[config getXmlWordPress]]];

    // Create url connection and fire request

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Verversen";
    hud.dimBackground = YES;

    [NewsTbView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIndent";
    TableViewCellHome *cell = (TableViewCellHome *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *CellName;

    CellName = @"TableViewCellHome";

    if (cell == nil) {

        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellName bundle:nil];

        cell = (TableViewCellHome *)c.view;
    }

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.txtDate setAlpha:0];
    [cell.txtTitle setAlpha:0];
    [cell.btnShare setAlpha:0];
    [cell.imgNews setAlpha:0];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"CustomCellAnimation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [cell.txtDate setAlpha:1];
    [cell.txtTitle setAlpha:1];
    //[cell.btnShare setAlpha:1];
    [cell.imgNews setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([catName isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        cell.txtTitle.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtDate.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imgNews setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.btnShare    addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(sharePost:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.txtTitle.text = [titleCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtDate.text = [dateCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imgNews setImage:[imageCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.btnShare    addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(sharePost:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row;

    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger total;
    if ([catName isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        total = imageArray.count;
    }
    else
    {
        total = imageCatArray.count;
    }
    return total;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

The `UITableView` has 7 dynamic cells. Do I need to add something to make it work for the whole tableview?

Full error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array' *** First throw call stack: (0x189516f50 0x195a201fc 0x1894184b0 0x1000984d0 0x18c628904 0x18c5c6db0 0x18c5c662c 0x18c4daff8 0x18c0cc258 0x18c0c6e20 0x18c0c6cd8 0x18c0c6560 0x18c0c6304 0x18c11cb84 0x18a417e74 0x1894c88e0 0x1894d6e90 0x1894d6df0 0x1894d5014 0x189415c20 0x18f0fdc0c 0x18c546fdc 0x10008cedc 0x196013aa0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Try to move `[self refresh];` at the beginning of the method `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Also in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you have many arrays and you access their object at the same index: indexPath.row. This is bad, use a singe array to fill your tableview.

Comment: self refrsh on top doesn't work. What do you mean with single array? Can you provide me some code? Thanks.

Comment: How does your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` methods look like?

Comment: @Levi see the updated code above with umberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: Add exception breakpoints (breakpoints tab -> +) and see at which line  does it crash. That array is empty, so see to it that it is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all of your NSMutableArray alloc, inits into your viewDidLoad method. What is happening is that you are reinitialising your arrays every refresh which erases the first and gives it only 1 available index.

Comment: I guess you only mean the NSMutableArray alloc inits from the refresh method? When I do this it works, but than I can keep on scrollin down and the cells are keep on repeating after refreshing

Comment: Yes only those methods. How many cells do you want? Does returning just a number like 7 in your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: Stop them repeating?

Comment: No this doesn't work. But the XML feed has to handle the number of rows in the section, this should not be static